# Uber API Reporting: Reference between Report Request and Report Success Notification

Tags: rest, workflow, webhooks, uber-api

We want to generate Uber Eats reports for multiple customers. Since everything is running on one system, the webhook notification for report generation will all arrive on the same local API.

**Now wondering if there is a relation between the webhook notification and the original report request?**

The reason is that we would like to check the signature of the notification and for this we need the appropriate client secret. Also we want to mark the original report request as completed.
So we need to be able to associate the notification to the right client or at least to the report request.

Is it possible that the workflow id we receive with the report request is included in the notification?
Or is the *job_id* what I'm looking for? In the [notification example](https://developer.uber.com/docs/eats/api/webhook-eats-report-success) this is not so clear to me.

Do you have other ideas here?

Answer (score 0):

The workflow_uuid in the POST /report response will map to the job_id within the webhook passed back after the report is finished generating.